# Управление отображением подписей полигонов на Яндекс.Карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api

коллеги!

Вывел на Я.Картах план земельных участков коттеджного посёлка.
Схема грузится достаточно быстро, но при отрисовке подписей полигонов очень заметны тормоза, задержка отрисовки до 4 секунд.

Отрисовка стандартная:

```
var polylabel = new ymaps.polylabel.create(myMap, objectManager);
```

Поэтому родилась идея, используя [данный пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polylabeler) 
, добавить на карту выпадающий список, тем самым "повесив" управление отображением подписями полигонов на пользователя через использование выпадающего списка.

Изначально схема выводится без подписей.
При желании пользователь выбирает из списка - "Показать номера участков" и они отрисовываются на карте.
Но как убрать подписи, если пользователь  захочет их скрыть?

```
    // Функция, которая управляет подписями полигонов.
    function updateLabels(type) {
        if (type == 1){
            // пользователь выбрал опцию - "Показать номера участков" 
            var polylabel = new ymaps.polylabel.create(myMap, objectManager);
        } else {
            // пользователь выбрал опцию - "Скрыть номера участков" 

            // что здесь должно быть, чтобы очистить карту от polylabel?

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Подписи удаляются следующим образом:

```
polylabel.destroy();
```